# Sorting out the geom_text() placement in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have a a dataset  with 3 columns called df

`Name`, `value`, `Freq`

I have constructed  a graph with `geom_bar()`  & `geom_text()` function

`ggplot(df, aes(x=name, fill=value, y=Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + geom_text(aes(label=Freq))`

with the output:

[image]

How would i be able to sort out the confused text label placement?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, fill=value, y=Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Freq),position = position_stack(0.9))
```